# Beep sound on logging in fedora32

Tags: fedora, laptop

I use a Lenovo IdeaPad V15 with Fedora 32. Recently, the device produces exactly five beeps (once) after user logging into the Linux system. But it doesn't occur with Windows 10. So this may not be a hardware issue. The laptop was bought only a few weeks ago. The beep sound occurs after boot when I enter my system user login password and login. Any solution for this?

**Edit 1 :** I did try this with another kernel of fedora32. And it just occurred the same way as before. And system sounds are muted.

My `boot.log` shows

```
Failed to start System Security Services Daemon
Failed to start Security Auditing Service
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "system password"? Like a BIOS password? Do the beeps occur when you enter the system password *and* log in, so once per entering the password?

Comment: It's NOT bios password. It's the user login password. It's occurs just once (five continuous beep sounds) after entering the password. Except that my Linux system works fine.

Comment: OK, well, perhaps you could clarify your question a bit further, then. As I understand it right now, it's on login manager.

Answer (score 2):

It's solved. I used a cleaner software,it might have removed the sssd directory in system.`reinstalling sssd-common` fixed the issue.